# Change the url inside a webview app depending on the notification IOS swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have swift webview app that using firebase remote notifications and i want to change the url inside the app depending on the notification sent from firebase console 
ex : in the notification "check our new website" -> takes us to the website inside the webview app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Create a function for loading the new website to the webView**

```
func loadNewSite(urlString: String) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

**2. Create an observer for firebase child changes and when .childChanged, call the function.**